# Problems cloning a repository on github for a college project

Tags: git, github, ssh, cmd, git-clone

I've been trying to clone a template for a project the we are ment to fork and download through cmd and I followed all the instructions for setting this up but now when I try on my laptop I it wont let me access it? I get the following error:

```
Cloning into 'ionic-assignment'...
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience this probably means you are using ssh and haven't set up ssh keys. Here is an explanation of what that is: http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Generating-Your-SSH-Public-Key

If you are using GitHub or BitBucket, this process is very straightforward.

GitHub: https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/

Comment: Thank you! Also one more question, is there a difference between using the cmd and using Git Bash?

Comment: The commands would be fairly different between cmd and Git Bash.  Do you have a reason to use one of them specifically?